# Copy colored terminal output to Excel and keep colors

Tags: bash, colors

I am trying to change the color of text based on some specific if condition.

Currently, it is displaying correctly on the console as per expectation. But when I copy colored text to Excel, the color is gone.

Is there any way to keep the color while copying to Excel as well?

I am using the command below to change the color of a variable.

```
echo -e -n "\033[1;36m$monthly2\e[0m\n"
```

`monthly2` is the name of variable.

Comment: This program converts the escape sequences into HTML: https://github.com/theZiz/aha/blob/master/aha.c . You could pipe your output through the `aha` binary to get HTML, then use that in Excel? My assumption is that Excel uses HTML/CSS to colorize text, but I don't *know* that.